# Motor and Phasor

Tags: motor, phasor

A group of induction motors with a total of 480 kW and a power factor of 0.8 lagging is to be partially replaced with synchronous motors of the same efficiency but leading power factor of 0.7. As the replacement program continues, the overall power factor is constantly improving. What percentage of the load will have been replaced when the system power factor reaches 0.9 lagging? (%)

I do not know how to approach this type of question.
Thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: Consider 480 kW at 0.9 lagging as the end result. What two loads will give you that result?

Comment: I dont really get what you mean? Could you explain it more clear plz?

Comment: This is a problem designed to help you learn how to analyze the situation, how to think about the problem and see the path to the solution. Think about what the statement of the problem tells you, sketch phasors to represent that and think about what the sum of the loads will look like when the end result is reached.

Comment: If u could give me a few steps? I would appreciate that

Comment: I will give you something in a few minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem designed to help you learn how to analyze the situation, how to think about the problem and see the path to the solution. Think about what the statement of the problem tells you, sketch phasors to represent that, and think about what the sum of the loads will look like when the end result is reached.

Consider 480 kW at 0.9 lagging as the end result. What two loads will give you that result?

Perhaps this will help:

[image]

Comment: I corrected the drawing labels.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!!! It is so clear to help me answer this question. I did not know how to relate the partial replacement with the overall load but now your graph makes so much sense. Appreciate!!!